# Java AES decrypt different results after saved and decrypted again

Tags: java, encryption, aes

When i run the scrypt my first decrypted result is correct:

> brother crowd mean guy ancient demand society before perfection glare
>   anger certain

When i save the encryptedText,salt(for example to a database) and want to decrypt again i get this.

> �Ŝ�,&6���;�m�an guy ancient demand society before perfection glare anger certain

***Update**
I think the problem was the way i handled the data(salt and iv). Now im able to encrypt and save -encryptText, randomIV, randomSalt to a database and decrypt it with masterPassword without problems.

Thanks for the help everyone you are great!

***Edited code, i ended up with this solution**

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Aes { 
private static int pswdIterations = 65536;
private static int keySize =  256;

public static String encrypt(String plainText, String password, String salt, String initializationVector) throws 
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, 
    NoSuchPaddingException, 
    InvalidParameterSpecException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, 
    BadPaddingException, 
    UnsupportedEncodingException, 
    InvalidKeyException, 
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
{   
    byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivBytes = initializationVector.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Derive the key, given password and salt.
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
            password.toCharArray(), 
            saltBytes, 
            pswdIterations, 
            keySize
    );

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return new Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);
}

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String password, String salt, String initializationVector ) throws 
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, 
    NoSuchPaddingException, 
    InvalidKeyException, 
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
    UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivBytes = initializationVector.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedText);

    // Derive the key, given password and salt.
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
            password.toCharArray(), 
            saltBytes, 
            pswdIterations, 
            keySize
    );

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    // Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector.
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

    byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
    try {
        decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
   }  

    public String generateSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        String s = new String(bytes);
        return s;
    }

    public String generateIV(String chars, int length) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
      buf.append(chars.charAt(rand.nextInt(chars.length())));
    }
    return buf.toString();
    }

    }
```

***Edited.Run Test**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//Passphrase and masterPassword
    String passPhrase = "stackoverflow is great";
    String masterPassword = "password";

    //-Aes
    Aes crypt = new Aes();

    // Aes generate random salt
    String genSalt = crypt.generateSalt();
    String tmpSalt = genSalt;
    // Aes generate random Iv
    String genIV =   crypt.generateIV("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 16);
    String tmpIV = genIV;

// Aes encrypt phrase
    String cipherPassPhrase = crypt.encrypt(passPhrase, masterPassword, tmpSalt, tmpIV);

    System.out.println(cipherPassPhrase);

// save cipherPassPhrase, tmpSalt, tmpIV to database ....decrypt with not stored masterPassword
 }
```

Comment: Seems to be encoding problem.Try UTF-16.Bud still if you just use plain ASCII chars this shoud have not happen.What encoding your database uses?

Comment: The seems to be a problem with saving or retrieving the data. Can you show the respective code?

Comment: Even if i dont save it to a database it has this problem. When i take the salt string and the encrypted string from the console and decrypt it also shows this unreadable things ^^ But why is 80% of the text ok only the beginning not?

Comment: You should generate salt and IV in one go, keep it secret, not generating both when doing new encryption.

Comment: Yeah my attention was to generate a random salt and iv. Fixed it in above solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few different problems with your code. First is how you're generating the salt...

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
String s = new String(bytes);
return s;
```

You're taking random data and trying to turn it in to a string, but the string constructor isn't expecting just any random data, it expects a string of text in some encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, or whatever.) Binary data can only be turned in to a string if you encode it, I'd just return the `bytes` array instead.

```
public byte[] generateSalt(int length) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[length];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Next, it's hard to say why your output was decrypting the specific way you've stated (with only the first block corrupted), but I'd wager a guess it has to do with incorrectly encoding the IV when you're saving it to the database. A better solution would be to prepend the salt and IV to the encrypted data, then strip them off when you need to decrypt.

```
public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {   
    //get salt    
    byte[] saltBytes = generateSalt(saltLength);

    // Derive the key
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, pswdIterations, keySize);

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    //encrypt the message
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] ivBytes = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    //prepend the salt and IV
    byte[] buffer = new byte[saltBytes.length + ivBytes.length + encryptedTextBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, buffer, 0, saltBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, buffer, saltBytes.length, ivBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(encryptedTextBytes, 0, buffer, saltBytes.length + ivBytes.length, encryptedTextBytes.length);
    return new Base64().encodeToString(buffer);
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    //strip off the salt and IV
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new Base64().decode(encryptedText));
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltLength];
    buffer.get(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.length);
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    buffer.get(ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.length);
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[buffer.capacity() - saltBytes.length - ivBytes.length];
    buffer.get(encryptedTextBytes);

    // Derive the key
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, pswdIterations, keySize);

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

    byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
    try {
        decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
}
```

It's very important to use a new IV every time you encrypt a piece of data, as it [helps to avoid known text attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/why-cant-the-iv-be-predictable-when-its-said-it-doesnt-need-to-be-a-secret/3500#3500).

Answer (score -1):

You code can encrypt A and decrypt A, but not encrypt A, encrypt B and decrypt A. 
Because the salt and initialization vector when encrypting A is overwritten when encrypting B.
I don't know what you want to archive. I left a usable code example.

```
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AESDemo {

    private static final String password = "test";
    private static String salt;
    private static int pswdIterations = 65536;
    private static int keySize = 256;
    //read from DB
    private byte[] ivBytes = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {

        // get salt
        if (salt == null)
            salt = generateSalt();
        byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
                pswdIterations, keySize);

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // encrypt the message
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return new Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception {

        byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedText);

        // Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
                pswdIterations, keySize);

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // Decrypt the message
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret,
                new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
        try {
            decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
    }

    public String generateSalt() {
        //get the salt from DB
        return "I hate salt";
    }
}

public class stackoverflow_test {

    public static void main(String[] ag) throws Exception{
        AESDemo d = new AESDemo();

        System.out.println("Encrypted string:" + d.encrypt("brother crowd mean guy ancient demand society before perfection glare anger certain"));           
        String encryptedText = d.encrypt("brother crowd mean guy ancient demand society before perfection glare anger certain");
        String encryptedText2 = d.encrypt("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Decrypted string:" + d.decrypt(encryptedText2));        
        System.out.println("Decrypted string:" + d.decrypt(encryptedText));         

    }
}
```

Result

```
Encrypted string:c7NXCBiq7tqzon39iPtkQLJ0chuXudS5oVDPdAr5S3q1245d3uJUVcyNUY77rpGeNvOp9hOldhiOM8mp2C/aOqqNyXx82zJt2V2EFtQkauCl/oY2EMENh1jCR6Nqf1lJ
Decrypted string:Hello World
Decrypted string:brother crowd mean guy ancient demand society before perfection glare anger certain
```

Comment: Thanks. But with your solution i could not do this. System.out.println("Decrypted string:" + d.decrypt(06scBq7GNv+jjJPpsJdOm+1mIdaWrk/SH2lO5yIIWvAQyiFo6gmq8anUloYlWLJQjW4NuUXRVfLN5Yp/OikicB9H/dMu7TGz5PPPV8yPqTOYYdK823mEOE5N0T084Cwv); I want to save the encryption and the seed in a db for example and than decrypt.

Comment: I modify the code such that IV and salt are a constant in code. such that you only need to save the encrypted text in DB, of course you can also save a IV and salt in DB, and read it when code starts.

Comment: @tom87416 Using a fixed IV is a security no-no as it opens you to known text attacks, and using a fixed salt (in general) makes you vulnerable to rainbow tables.